# Pass argument to dplyr

Tags: r, function, arguments, dplyr

I'd like to pass argument to a function which use `dplyr`.

The idea is to transform the data of a specific column *(my argument)* of a data frame.

**Here is an illustrative example:**

```
example = function(x){
  df %>%
    mutate( paste0(x, '_with_noise') = x + rnorm(n(), 0, 0.01))
}
```

The problem is I obtain this error message:

```
> Error: unexpected '=' in: "  df %>%
>     mutate( paste(x, '_with_noise', sep = '') ="
> > } Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I also tried to use these but I have the exact same error.

- `mutate_` instead of `mutate`
- `quote()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you would use `mutate_`.

```
example = function(x){
  tx <- lazyeval::interp(~z+rnorm(n(), 0, 0.01), z=as.name(x))
  tn <- paste0(x, '_with_noise')
  df %>%
    mutate_( .dots=setNames(list(tx), tn))
}

example("a")
example("b")
```

There are examples of this in the NSE vignette from dplyr (`vignette("nse","dplyr")`). This method is safer than pasting arbitrary strings and evaluating the results.

Comment: The big advantage of `dplyr` which is the readibility is totaly lost with NSE.
**Whay a pity !**

Comment: @Ricol solving a specific problem will almost always be simpler than solving a class of problems. (I think dplyr could do better with SE, but I can't quite figure out what components you need)

Answer (score 0):

The `paste` command doesn't work here within the `mutate`, so it is better to assign the name of the variable to an additional variable `y`

```
example = function(x){
  y <- paste(x, '_with_noise', sep = '')
  df %>%
    mutate(y = x + rnorm(n(), 0, 0.01))
}
```

So if your data is

```
a <- c("A","B","C")
b <- c(2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

> df
  a b
1 A 2
2 B 3
3 C 4
```

calling

```
> example(df$b)
```

leads to the result

```
  a b        y
1 A 2 2.013845
2 B 3 2.998154
3 C 4 3.987750
```

Comment: Thanks, The `paste` function doesn't work because x is not a string.
If I put x between commas then the `mutate` doesn't work.

Comment: And if you put `x` between commas, x becomes a string, and in consequence, you can't perform arithmetic operations on it anymore, so it seems logical that `mutate` won't work anymore then.

Comment: You're right. Actually this solution doesn't work because the name of the noisy variable didn't is y and not x_with_noise.

Answer (score -1):

To make this trick you have to put your entire command into `paste` function.
BTW, it's better to use `paste0` instead of `paste(..., sep = '')`

This is a working example.

```
example = function(x){
  y <- as.character(substitute(x))
  eval(parse(text = paste0(
    "df %>% mutate(", y, "_with_noise =", y, " + rnorm(n(), 0, 0.01) )"
    )))
}

set.seed(99)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(10, 25, T), ncol = 5, 
                            dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:5]) ))
example(b)
#    a  b c d e b_with_noise
# 1  6 10 6 7 3     9.996149
# 2  2  7 6 4 1     7.008946
# 3  7  3 2 2 9     2.991608
# 4 10  4 7 1 6     3.995421
# 5  6  2 7 2 8     2.001143
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot.
Let me know if there is a way to use a simpler syntax